# how can i select child element via jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="slider-box-1">
  <div class="swipe-box-1"></div>
  <div class="space-1"></div>
  <div>the version type</div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the child which have no class or id.

Comment: not selector would be helpful here, please check http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-not-selector-example/ for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector for this

```js
$(".slider-box-1").find("div:not([class])").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-box-1">
  <div class="swipe-box-1">swipe-box-1</div>
  <div class="space-1">space-1</div>
  <div>the version type</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Include support for :not([id]) as well and this answer is golden. Also, as a technicality, OP asked for children, not descendants - for that use case, I would use .children() instead of .find()